# Date.today is not a function after J-Query 3.x Upgrade

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, arrays, date

After recently updating my local J-Query library from 1.9.1 to 3.6.0 I have noticed some strange issues.  I did not see anything online for this, and most of these functions are standard JavaScript functions I believe, and not J-Query.  I am seeing that Date() objects are undefined.  Also the following errors with Date and Array objects are happening.  If I revert the code to 1.9.1 there is no issue.  *Also this is a Node.js project, I dont know if that matters.

TypeError: Date.today is not a function
at Object. (main.js:8:126614)

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes')

TypeError: i.add is not a function

Sample Code

```
        var today = Date.today();
```

**UPDATE:**
It looks like the code that is not working is coming from this node.js package.

https://github.com/datejs/Datejs

When I change the code to

```
var today = new Date();
var numberOfDays = today.add(5).days();
```

Then there is a problem with the add method, see the error listed above.

```
// Type definitions for DateJS
// Project: http://www.datejs.com/
// Definitions by: David Khristepher Santos <https://github.com/rupertavery>
// Definitions: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped
```

Comment: `today()` is not a standard method on the Date object in javascript.

Comment: Thanks you @Vektor you are right, that method is coming from a node.js package called datejs, it has not been updated since 2007, and seems to not work when I change to J-Query 3.x.  Any ideas?

Comment: That's not how to use the library. Check it's docs

Comment: Are you sure Datejs has a `days` method? not just `day`?, try `Date.today().addDays(1)` or `Date.today().add(1).day()` or `Date.today().add({ days: 1 })`

Comment: Yes, here is my code.  It works fine with J-Query 1.9.1.  
                maxAllowedDate = today.add(parseInt(result.MaxDuration)).days();

Comment: The post only partly describes the issue (not enough to know why Datejs is failing) and doesn't present a question. What course of action are you pursuing? What have you tried? Are you willing to fork the repo and update it to work with later versions of JQuery?

Comment: The issue is updating JQuery to 3.x, it causes Datejs lib not to work.  I dont think I can say it any clearer.  With JQuery 1.9.1 it works fine.  I am willing to try anything thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend Date.js on the basis that it modifies built–in objects like Date, Date.prototype and Number.prototype. It hasn't been officially updated since 2007, whereas the objects it modifies have been. It's also very US centric, e.g. culture info is only provided for en-US, and  functions like *getTimezoneAbbreviation* are reliant on language, which is illogical.

Comment: @RobG it has variations for other cultures.  Anything I do to make datejs work with the setup I have?  I dont want to re-write all the code I have.  On a note, if I add the date.js file manually and add a script tag to the html it works fine.  Not sure how the npm install works or what I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do we flag this for delete, it was early in the process and my description of the issue was not clear.  A better description/resolution is listed here:  [Datejs lib not working after Upgrade to J-Query 3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70463525/datejs-lib-not-working-after-upgrade-to-j-query-3-x)

Answer (score -2):

today() is not a method in javascript, maybe you should try this `const today = new Date();

console.log(today);`

Comment: Not a bad answer, thanks.  However I did not originally mention that I am using the Datejs lib.  I would like to continue to use that lib with JQuery 3.x, any ideas how I can make that work, or possibly another lib that does similar thing.  Thanks!

Comment: @MattyMerrix—asking for recommendations for libraries and other off–site resources is off topic here. Unfortunately the trend has been to large, heavyweight libraries to the detriment of smaller, lighter libraries like Date.js. The fundamental design of Date.js in modifying built–in objects is flawed (and has been considered bad practice for ages), the approach of moment.js which creates its own date wrapper objects is much preferred. Consider a library like [*Fecha.js*](https://github.com/taylorhakes/fecha) and adding your own extensions.