# Datejs lib not working after Upgrade to J-Query 3.x

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, node-modules, datejs

I have a node.js project where we are using the following lib.

https://github.com/datejs/Datejs

After a recent update of our local J-Query file from 1.9.1 to 3.6.0 this lib stopped working.

Sample Code

```
    var today = Date.today();
```

Errors

TypeError: Date.today is not a function at Object. (main.js:8:126614)

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes')

TypeError: i.add is not a function

When I change the code to

```
var today = new Date();
var numberOfDays = today.add(5).days();
```

Then there is a problem with the add method, see the error listed above.

Question, is there anyway to make this lib work with the latest J-Query?  The repo appears old and stale, no new releases since 2007, is there any other similar libs that I could try?

Comment: The DateJS library is not dependent on jQuery, so it's likely that the update to jQuery has broken some other logic and is having a knock on effect.

Comment: Can you elaborate my friend, or anything I can check for/research/debug?  We had a previous issue where JQuery 3.x had altered the load order of some of our other js files and causing them not to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I think I finally found the answer.

var parsedate = require('datejs');

Basically, this line was previously removed to help clean-up un-used variables, the previous Jquery upgrade caused issues with the loading order of some of our js files.  Although parsedate is never used, this line is still needed to include the datejs lib.

#Winning #TigerBlood